# Anchored VWAP doesn't draw the indicator after I selected input on the chart

Tags: pine-script

I tried to use this script https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/ but the indicator doesn't draw.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VWAP works with `volume` but no volume information is available on `DJI:TVC`. The vendor does not provide this data.

[image]